# C# store int and bytes inside two dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

Is there a way, to store a int and bytes inside a 2 dimensional array?

For example:

```
int[,] WeaponAddresses = new int[,] { { 0x4F0, 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 } };
```

I would appreciate any kind of help

Comment: 1. You can create array of objects. 2. You can create array of arrays of some structure.

Answer (score 2):

1. You could make it an array of objects.
2. create a structure with an int and byte property and declare a 1 dimensional array of the structure.

   ```
   public struct MyObj
   {
     public int IntValue {get;set;}
     public byte[] ByteValue {get;set;}
   }     

   public class TestClass
   {
      MyObj[] arrayOfObjects;
   }
   ```